# Serial port hang up on first send

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I having a problem with SerialPort; when I try to write to it, it get hang up.

```
Private Function Conectar(ByVal PortName As String, ByVal PortBps As UInteger) As Boolean
        If Not Me.SmsSerialPort.IsOpen Then
            Try
                Me.PrintLog(String.Format("Port {0} at {1} BPS", PortName, PortBps.ToString))
                Me.SmsSerialPort.PortName = PortName
                Me.SmsSerialPort.BaudRate = CInt(PortBps)
                Me.SmsSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
                Me.SmsSerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
                Me.SmsSerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500
                Me.SmsSerialPort.Open()
                Me.SmsSerialPort.RtsEnable = True
                Me.LastValidCom = PortName
            Catch ex As Exception
                Me.PrintLog("Error: " + ex.Message, True)
                Interaction.MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                Dim result As Boolean = False
                Return result
            End Try
        End If
        Me.PrintLog("Starting modem", True)

        'The following line was added to test the COM comunication directly without using SendAtCommand function but doesn't work either.
        Me.SmsSerialPort.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)

        If Not Me.SendAtCommand("AT" & vbCrLf & "AT" & vbCrLf & "ATV1", 3, True) Then
            Me.OkRecibido = False
            Return False
        End If
End Function
```

I use the same port with two another application, one designed by me and the other is designed by Microsoft and both works ok with the same port.

There's a way to know what is waiting for?
Any way to debug this more in deep that the green line and arrow that Visual Studio shows me?

Comment: surround `.Write` / `.sendAtCommand` with  Try....Catch; and add the exception details to your question for more clarification

Comment: I get no error, the code just go away from my code to the SerialPort library code. I just see a green line and a green arrow if I pause the program. The strange is that if I copy the code to a new application it works perfect. This code was recovered with a VB decompiler because I lost the original code and use an exe to reverse the code and update the old backup that I have.

Comment: There are too many reasons like Incorrect Port (Com Port is machine dependent), Your device is not working properly, Write cycle is executing well but you are getting reply with in readtimeout period, baud-rate mismatch, you are closing and opening the port too fast,etc etc..... We need to know the exact situation, may be you can post your associated code here.

Comment: I tried the program in other machine and is working ok, Can be a virus or something? Because is the only program that can't access the serial port. If I copy the code in a whole new application it works ok.